# What notation is this from probability?

Tags: symbols

I usually see this one when it comes to probability.

What notation is this and how can I do it on latex?

[image]

Comment: Looks very `\mathcal{N}`-y to me.

Comment: It is usually used for the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: Of topic; In probability N often denotes the Normal distribution. Often it is in caligraphic font.